# How to repalce all blank spaces with <br/> tag in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, replace

I'm showing from DB some data, via ajax, datatype ist "string" that contains blank spases between words. How can I finde every of it and replace it wit 
 tag, so every word will be in a new line?

here is my ajax code:

```
var tableId = "weekEvents";

 function loadWeekData() {

// Append database data here

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/JsonWeekEvents",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, val) {

           


            var trow = $('<tr class=content/>').data("id", val.Id);
            //trow.append('<td>' + val.Id + "&nbsp;" + '</td>');
            trow.append('<td style="padding:5px; width:auto; height:60px" class="FSE">'+val.FSE+'</td>');
            trow.append('<td>' +
                
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="monVal" class="desc_NumM">' + val.Monday + '</div >' +
               
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td>' +
                
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="tueVal" class="desc_NumT">' + val.Tuesday + '</div >' +
               
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td>' +
               
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="wedVal" class="desc_NumW">' + val.Wednesday + '</div >' +
              
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td>' +
                
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="thurVal" class="desc_NumTr">' + val.Thursday + '</div >' +
              
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td>' +
                
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="friVal" class="desc_NumF">' + val.Friday + '</div >' +
                
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td>' +
                
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="satVal" class="desc_NumSa">' + val.Saturday + '</div >' +
                
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td>' +
                
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="sunVal" class="desc_NumSu">' + val.Sunday + '</div >' +
                
                '</td>');
            tbody.append(trow);
            tab.append(tbody);
           
        });

        $("#" + tableId).html(tab);
}
```

Basicly its about valuers "val.Monday", "val.Tuesday", "val.Wednesday"...."val.Sunday", those are my data from DB. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string repalce function as explained in [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp][1] . In your case, it could be like,

```
var res = str.replace(" ", "</br>");
```

Comment: I've tryed, but it works with normal string if i specifyed it, but not with data from db, but it could be so that I've done it wrong. You mean: var res = $('#weVal').val() and then res.replace(" ", "<br/>")?

Comment: DId you try val.Monday.replace(" ", "</br>") ?

Comment: Have already tryed, it doesn't work in Ajax call for some reason

Comment: NO! This given piece of  code runs once you get data from ajax call. It does not have anything to do with ajax or server.

Comment: Can you paste printed val from console log ?

Comment: I have no idea, show me what You mean, where belongs Your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217633/discussion-between-pharsa-thapa-and-dimitri).

Comment: Yes, I've tryed it with other fields, it works perfectley! Thank You one more time!

Comment: No problem. Enjoy your rest of the day. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi, still here? Could You take a look at my table one more time, somehow it works only from monday to wednesday, if i try to append replace for other days it collapses for some reason